# Android: How to access different layouts depending of screen density in XML

Tags: android, android-layout

I am wondering how to get different XML layout files to be read depending of density of the screen.

Now when I enter a layout file and set to so that it has a couple of buttons and have them set to a specific position, the position changes when I change to another screen density in the emulator. This is what should be happening what i understand- but How do I get the program to use different layouts depending of densities?

I have been reading on android dev. page on how to develop for different screens, but I didn't get the examples which were there.

I have been using dp/dip on sizes so no need to suggest that =)

Answer (score 5):

you can do it by creating a layout for each standart screen sizes,

you can find [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range) how to do it.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

it means you should create sub-directory named as ("layout", "layout-small","layout-large","layout-xlarge","layout-xlarge-land") in res folder.

than create a main xml for each one with the same name.

Answer (score 3):

By placing the layout XML files in different folders you can get Android to load the correct one depending on the screen density. For example, if you layout is called "main.xml":

- Placing the file in /res/layout-ldpi/main.xml will mean it is used only in low density (or above)
- Placing the file in /res/layout-mdpi/main.xml will mean it is used only in medium density (or above)
- Placing the file in /res/layout-hdpi/main.xml will mean it is used only in high density (or above)
- Placing the file in /res/layout-xhdpi/main.xml will mean it is used only in extra-high density

You can do the same sort of thing with all resources- drawables, strings, dimensions etc. (e.g. drawable-mdpi, or values-en [values only to be used in an English locale]). You can find the whole list of different device set-ups supported by this system at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html (Table 2: Configuration Qualifier names)